# How to get Apache Tomcat running with jsp files?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, web.xml

I'm new to web servers and would appreciate your help. I was given JSP files (and some other css and javascript files) and I'm trying to figure out a way to quickly get these JSP files up and running on the Apache Tomcat server just to view them. I got the Tomcat server running using Eclipse, but now I'm not sure how I can run the JSP files. Do I need a web.xml file? I've looked at some examples of web.xml but I am not sure what pieces are needed.

If there is anything that you can give me to lead me in the right direction, it would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html

In short:
Install the WTP extension and create a new Dynamic Web Project. Set the project to run with the Tomcat managed by Eclipse.
Then copy your JSPs to the project and start Tomcat through Eclipse.
Maybe you can convert your existing project to a Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I managed to get a test project working by following http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html. I'm having trouble loading the JSPs that were given to me. It wasn't sent to me as an entire project that I can import into my workspace. I tried making a sample app and copy/pasted the JSPs into the workspace webcontent folder but it's not registering on the server. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Right click on your project an select "Run As" -> "Run on server". Also, you can look at the project properties, especially "Deployment assembly", to see if for JSPs get published.

Comment: Thanks. I also found out that using the Java EE IDE was preferred since I was previously running on only the Juno version that didn't have the WTP extensions.